# How to override Paypal Standard Model

Tags: overrides, paypal, model

I am trying to override the Paypal Standard Model using the following files:

app/code/local/Me/Paypal/etc/Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <me_paypal>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </me_paypal>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>
          <paypal>
              <rewrite>
                  <standard>Me_Paypal_Model_Standard</standard>
              </rewrite>
          </paypal>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Me/Paypal/Model/Standard.php

```
class Me_Paypal_Model_Standard extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract{

        //my changed code here

}
```

The problem is that the changes I make to the Standard models code do not seem to be getting applied.  Have I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try
`app/code/local/Me/Paypal/Model/Standard.php`
instead of
`app/code/local/Me/Paypal/Models/Standard.php`

Comment: Sorry my bad, it is a typo on the question not the site itself.  I have tried both "Model" and "model"  neither work although I don't know the difference.

Comment: Is your extension listed under System > Configuration > Advanced > Disable Modules Output?

Comment: It is listed as enabled

Comment: is Config.xml just capitalised in the question? it should be lower case config.xml

Comment: super thanks.  I can never get my head around the capitalization rules in magento modules

Comment: No worries, it is a bit of a tricky start but if you start by looking at working modules you will get there.